# Docker -- Multistage DockerFile for Angular app. COPY Failed

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I am attempting to create a custom image for my angular application by using the following multi-stage DockerFile:

```
FROM node:8.11.2-alpine as node

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine
COPY --from=node . /dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

However, when I attempt to build the image, I receive the following error in the console window:

```
Step 8/9 : COPY --from=node . /dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY failed: stat 
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/be4bf1ad6bf693062d3bbcebf060281
e331c3135e3178068f3f9bf91113da200/merged/dist: no such file or directory
```

I am still relatively new to Docker and building my own Dockerfile, and everything I have tried/researched thus far has always returned the same error message.

My folder structure for my application resembles the following:

```
--Docker-Compose.yml
--Angular App
  --ClientApp
    --Dockerfile
    --nginx.conf
    --package.json
    --src(folder)
      --index.html
```

My nginx-conf file needed for the actual build looks like this:

```
   server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

Has anyone else ran into this issue? Any positive direction on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Still looking for answers, just not sure what else to try at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this line you have 3 parameters for copy: `COPY --from=node . /dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html`

So, you have `.`, `/dist/` and `/usr/share/nginx/html`. You should have only two and probably that's why it's failing.